# What is the best way to initiate parameters on a Python library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shared-libraries

I have a homegrown python library. As it is a library, it should be initialized with parameters every time it is used, based on different projects using it. For example, here is the sample pseudo code:

```
import myownlibrary 

myownlibrary.init('path_to_config_file_containing_details_to_process_data')
```

Any idea how this can be achieved?
A sample reference code will be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added it to the `__init__.py` as below

```
global configpath

def setpath(self, pathpassedin):
   self.configpath = pathpassedin
   print("Value passed in: ", pathpassedin)
```

I thought `self` was required, but having `self` also requires that the method be called as below:

```
import myownlibrary as mylib

myownlibrary.setpath(mylib, 'path_to_config_file')
```

Not sure if this is the way to set this up. Would appreciate feedback